# spring @RequestMapping Variable values like url

Tags: spring-mvc

I have this `@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{path}",method = RequestMethod.GET)`
in my controller

I need `{path}` variable in some different ways for example : path could be "image.png" in other time could be "/resources/images/image.png"..

**My question**: Can spring handle variable like paths --> `"/resources/images/image.png"`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882791/asterisk-after-string-in-requestmapping/34892981#34892981

Answer (score 1):

`/` and `.` will break the variable into pieces. Using the path variables without any additional configurations you have to break even the file name into two separate path variables like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{filename}/{extension}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public [ReturnType] myMethod(
   @PathVariable("filename") String file,
   @PathVariable("extension") String ext) { ... }
```