# Asterisk after string in @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What's the meaning of the asterisk in this case:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

What I understand is that `*` means space but what `**` means after the `admin`? How does the double asterisk affect a url like "localhost:8080/project/admin"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths, like,

```
1. admin
2. admin123
3. adminavv
4. adminadmin
```

will be matched. Use `request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE )` for getting `"admin" + variable` child path.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `**` will match zero or more 'directories' in the path. Doing so, it will match anything who is 'children' of `admin`.